# How can I iterate through numpy 3d array

Tags: python, loops, numpy

So I have an array:

```
array([[[27, 27, 28],
        [27, 14, 28]],

       [[14,  5,  4],
        [ 5,  6, 14]]])
```

How can I iterate through it and on each iteration get the [a, b, c] values, I try like that:

```
for v in np.nditer(a):
    print(v)
```

but it just prints

```
27
27
28
27
14
28
14
5
4
5
6
```

I need:

```
[27 27 28]
[27 14 28]...
```

Comment: As an aside: what is the calculation you want to do with the individual triplets?

Comment: @9769953 I need to convert hsv values to rgb

Comment: It sounds like that can be done without iterating through the individual elements. If you add the formula, someone may show how to do that in one go. Or ask a new question on that.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278323/converting-image-from-rgb-to-hsv-color-space or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852345/hsv-to-rgb-color-conversion

Comment: Look at `ndindex`.  It uses `nditer` to generate indices for a subarray, such as (2,2).  Look at its code if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something ugly as

```
for i in range(len(your_array)):
    for j in range(len(your_array[i])):
        print(your_array[i][j])
```

Comment: In `numpy` it looks more idiomatic to index with `your_array[i, j]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
b = a.reshape(-1, 3)
for triplet in b:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you want to iterate on the first 2 dimensions of the array, returning the 3rd (as 1d array).

```
In [242]: y = np.array([[[27, 27, 28],
     ...:         [27, 14, 28]],
     ...: 
     ...:        [[14,  5,  4],
     ...:         [ 5,  6, 14]]])
```

Double loops are fine, as is reshaping to a (4,2) and iterating.

`nditer` isn't usually needed, or encouraged as an iteration mechanism (its documentation needs a stronger disclaimer).  It's really meant for C level code.  It isn't used much in Python level code.  One exception is the `np.ndindex` function, which can be useful in this case:

```
In [244]: for ij in np.ndindex(y.shape[:2]):
     ...:     print(ij, y[ij])
     ...:     
(0, 0) [27 27 28]
(0, 1) [27 14 28]
(1, 0) [14  5  4]
(1, 1) [ 5  6 14]
```

`ndindex` uses `nditer` in `multi_index` mode on a temp array of the specified shape.

Where possible try to work without iteration.  Iteration, with any of these tricks, is relatively slow.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as having arrays within an array. So within array **v** you have array **a** which in turn contains the triplets **b**

```
import numpy as np
na = np.array

v=na([[[27, 27, 28], [27, 14, 28]], [[14,  5,  4],[ 5,  6, 14]]])

for a in v:
    for b in a:
        print b
```

Output:

```
[27 27 28]
[27 14 28]
[14  5  4]
[ 5  6 14]
```

Alternatively you could do the following,

```
v2 = [b for a in v for b in a]
```

Now all your triplets are stored in **v2**

```
[array([27, 27, 28]),
 array([27, 14, 28]),
 array([14,  5,  4]),
 array([ 5,  6, 14])]
```

..and you can access them like a 1D array eg

```
print v2[0]
```

gives..

```
array([27, 27, 28])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (useful for arbitrary dimensionality of the array containing the n-tuples):

```
a_flat = a.ravel()
n = 3   
m = len(a_flat)/n
[a_flat[i:i+n] for i in range(m)]
```

or in one line (slower):

```
[a.ravel()[i:i+n] for i in range(len(a.ravel())/n)]
```

or for further usage within a loop:

```
for i in range(len(a.ravel())/n):
    print a.ravel()[i:i+n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshape the array `A` (whose shape is `n1, n2, 3`) to array `B` (whose shape is `n1 * n2, 3`), and iterate through `B`. Note that `B` is just `A`'s view. `A` and `B` share the same data block in the memory, but they have different array headers information where records their shapes, and changing values in `B` will also change `A`'s value. The code below:

```
    a = np.array([[[27, 27, 28],[27, 14, 28]],
                  [[14,  5,  4],[ 5,  6, 14]]])   
    b = a.reshape((-1, 3))   
    for last_d in b:
        a, b, c = last_d
        # do something with last_d or a, b, c
```