# Convert single 8 bit value (0-255) to 3, 8 bit values

Tags: python, math, colors, rgb

Alright so the best way I can really explain this is on this site https://www.colorspire.com/rgb-color-wheel/ there is a color wheel when you first load the site don't move the little pointer in the square to select stuff. Just go to the bar that you can drag and drag it you'll see the `r g b` values change but you will also notice that one of the values is always 0, how can I recreate that but instead of the bar you drag you input a single 8 bit value (out of 255) so I can run the program with the value lets say 170 and it would somehow map that to a certain color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually changing the hue when you move the bar so try this

```py
import colorsys
color = input("Enter a value from 0-359:")
test_color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(color/360.0, 1, 1)
```

### References

> [HSV to RGB Color Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852345/hsv-to-rgb-color-conversion)

Comment: Thats kinda what I want, I want the input to be out of 255, and instead of each value being out of 1 they need to be out of 255

Comment: Yeah but that's not how hue works. The color bar is a number from 0-359 not 1-255. (RGB is from 1-255)

Comment: I just multiplied each value by 255 then did math.trunc()

Comment: And I made it more specific just now by instead of doing "test_color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(int(value)/360.0, 1, 1)" I did "    test_color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(int(value)/255.0, 1, 1)"

Comment: yes, and that was just my code while testing it I shortened it down.

Answer (score 0):

```
    test_color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(int(value)/255.0, 1, 1)
    r, g, b = test_color
    r = (r * 255)
    r = math.trunc(r)
    g = (g * 255)
    g = math.trunc(g)
    b = (b * 255)
    b = math.trunc(b)
    fg.orange = Style(RgbFg(r, g, b))
    msg = fg.orange + str(f"  r = {r}, g = {g}, b = {b}")
    print(msg)
```